# jrecorder jquery conflicts

Tags: jquery, conflict

I am having a jquery conflict error. please provide a solution.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script>
var r=jQuery.noConflict(true);
://function related to 'r' here....
<body>
<script src='recorder/jquery.js'></script>
<script src="recorder/recorder.js"></script>
//these files are present...cross checked twice...
<script>
var j=$.noConflict(true);
j(document).ready(function(){
j.jRecorder({
    : //all settings here
});
});
</script>
</body>
```

The upper part is working perfectly but the lower part is not working at all. I am using jrecorder : http://www.sajithmr.me/jrecorder-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use this structure

```
 $.noConflict();
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
      });
```

use

```
$(function() {
  // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
```

insted of

```
J.j(document)....
```

Explanation:
`$.noConfilct()` - set corrcet valut to alias of JQuery. it doent return $.

from Docs

Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just as jQuery does.
 In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so all functionality is available without
 using $. If we need to use another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, ***we can return control of $ back*** to the other library with a call to $.noConflict():

For more detail take a look here [jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: you should use $.jRecorder not J